From Abstract Syntax Tree to machine code. Functions as first-class objects compilation?
I have created a front-end for my language. I have also been able to transpile to C so that it can be compiled. In this language, functions are treated as first-class objects.
Is it possible to implement in LLVM IR? Or would compiling into some assembly be the better course of action?
CONTEXT:
My problem, is that I believe in C, functions cannot be treated as first class objects. Admittedly this hasn't got many use cases, but either way, this is my goal for the language.
Take this example.
union Func {
    void foo( void );
    void bar( void );
};
union Funcs getDynamicFunc( int *flag );
int flag;
union Funcs func = getDynamicFunc( &flag );
/* 
let dynamic function memory gets wiped 
*/
if( flag == 1 ) {
    func.foo();
} else if( flag == 2 ) {
    func.bar();
} else return -1;

Firstly, this wouldn't compile, it would have to be function pointers in the union.
Now if the getDynamicFunc got the function contents from some volatile memory? Say, another process? Well if they were first-class objects, then all would be ok, because the union is in our stack and holds the actual function code.

C's notion of function pointer is how functions are made first class in that language.  Any other language that has first class functions does the same as C under the covers.  C++, other languages use vtables (witness tables, etc...) which in C would be arrays of function pointers.  Some languages use fat pointers under the covers, whuch are simply a pair of different pointers.

In short, not sure what you're looking for. Operating systems are set up for separating code & data, using pointers to code, to data. Any thing else (e.g. separate variables, arrays, first-class functions, virtual methods, interfaces, traits, closures, continuations,  recursion,  ...) has to be composed from these, even if hidden from programmers by some languages.

@ErikEidt I guess what I mean is that the actual function code, what would be in the ".code" section, would be able to instead reside in the stack, and even get unwound. Also then we could do the sizeof() operator on a function, dynamically allocating these ".code" sections even. Thanks.

Ok, that is very unusual so you'll have to create a custom runtime to support that.
